# Best practice in Rails to disable a particular Bootstrap Modal for user Window Duration/Session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, session

I am looking accomplish a bit of behavior. I currently have a bootstrap Modal that fires automatically on a window page load.   If a user hits the close button, I'd like to disable that button from auto-loading again if the user visits the same page, as long as the same window is open.

```
     javascript:
       $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#vModal').appendTo("body");
         $('#vModal').modal('show');
       });
```

With Rails, what would be the best practice solution(s) to handle this edge case? I've had this issue a few times and never felt confident in my solution.  I was thinking of adding some session data? Any best practice tips/solutions would be really helpful.

Thanks!

---- solved ---

```
javascript:
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#vModal').appendTo("body");
    $('#vModal').modal('show');
  });

  $("#closed_gift").click(function() {
    document.cookie = "clicked=true";
  });
```

Comment: You should probably use `document.cookie = "clicked=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT;"` instead, because otherwise the cookie will expire when the browser is closed.

Comment: great tip.. this is pretty important!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this behavior, I would use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) set through JavaScript. Cookies will persist after the page is refreshed. If the user closes the modal, you could set a cookie, and then in your `$(document).ready` function, you would only show the modal if the cookie is not already set. The page I linked to has a full cookie reader/writer function that might home in handy.

Please comment if you would like more detail.